# Working with many variables in a for loop

Tags: perl

Ok so I have alot of variables in numeric order. Unfortunately they are not in an array. Now I need to do some work on each variable and was wondering what would be the smartest way to do so. I've read that using a variable in a variable name is dangerous, since it can cause complications. I was thinking of something like this below but would appreciate guidance :)

```
my $var10
my $var20
my $var30
...
my $var300

For (my $t = 10; $t < 301; $t++){$var$t ...}
```

EDIT: 
let's say I wanted to push these variable's into an array. How would I best proceed?

Comment: Any particular reason you haven't put them in an array?

Comment: Are these global variables or lexical variables? (`our` or `my`?)

Comment: Using 300 scalar variables instead of 1 array is somewhat like keeping all your money in pennies, except worse. There is no benefit whatsoever by doing it your way, only downsides.

Comment: This is the opposite end to *"How do I store my data in variables whose names are constructed at run time"*. And the reason why that is a *bad idea* is exactly this - you can't tell what variables to use later on.

Comment: The reason they aren't in an array in the first place is because these variable get created after a DB request. They are put into variables because not all the results from the BD request are of the same type.

Comment: @user2001504 You are completely misunderstanding Perl data structures. What you call a "variable" is a scalar. An array is a list of scalars. There are no "types", any data point can be stored in any scalar. In short: If you can store it in a scalar, you can store it in an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pull all your variables' values into a hash using

```
my %var;
{
  for (1 .. 30) {
    my $n = $_ * 10;
    $var{$n} = eval "\$var$n";
  }
}
```

then you can

```
for (1 .. 30) {
  my $t = $_ * 10;
  $var{$t}...
}
```

or just

```
for my $t (sort { $a <=> $b } keys %var) {
  $var{$t}...
}
```

but *don't* do it again!

Comment: One "no eval" solution would be to disable strict refs and do something like `for (0 .. 300) { no strict 'refs'; our $name = "var$_"; $var{$name} = $$name; }`

Comment: @TLP: Except that won't work if `$var10` etc. are lexicals. That's why I asked in my comment, but the OP doesn't want to tell!

Comment: There is no reason to be wary of `eval` here. Its use with tainted data (derived from an external source) is the only situation where it can be risky.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Sry Borodin, I edited my OP to clarify

Answer (score 10):

Refactor so that they *are* in an array.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is the only reasonable answer possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a hash:

```
%h = ('var10' => 42, 'var20' => ...)
```